# Guava: How do I convert Collection<T> to Collection<Optional<T>>?

Tags: java, collections, guava, option-type

In Guava, if I have a `Collection<T>` - is there any existing function in Guava that will allow me to easily transform it to a `Collection<Optional<T>>` ?

Comment: I've never heard of Guava before reading this question.... but from looking at the API and me knowing C# and Java okay, why wouldn't something like this achieve your purposes?

    Iterables.transform<Optional<T>, T>(collection,
        new Function<Optional<T>, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Optional<T> apply(T) {
                return Optional.of<T>(i);
            }
        });

Comment: I've actually never done generics with static methods and it's been a while since I've used generics on method calls, in general, so maybe my syntax is slightly off, but is that the sort of thing you were looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the normal way:

```
 return Collections.transform(collection, new Function<T, Optional<T>>() {
   public Optional<T> apply(T t) {
     return Optional.of(t);
   }
 }
```

..although it'd probably be better to do it with an explicit, strict construction.

Comment: Thanks Louis. I was hoping this would already exist on an API somewhere and I missed it. I'll just add it to my growing class [StuffGuavaIsMissing.java](http://pastebin.com/wFmbw5FE)

Comment: If you really want it, file an issue request, but if something doesn't feel like that common a case to us, we'll often go ahead and let you add it to your own utilities if you want, rather than add it to Guava when we're not sure.

Comment: Note: the `Optional.of` might be `Optional.fromNullable`, depending on  what this user is trying to do.

Comment: Hehe nah don't worry - I've just been spoiled by the comprehensive APIs from the likes of [FunctionalJava](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/index.html)

Comment: I made a quick pass through StuffGuavaIsMissing for inspiration.  A couple notes FYI:

FluentIterable may be getting transformAndConcat, which is the same as your flatTransform.

Iterables.any looks to be identical to your exists.